# Refactoring if-else blocks python with context managers?

Tags: python, refactoring, contextmanager

I'm looking to refactor some repetitive code blocks that looks like the following:

```
if condition == True:
    print("Doing some light work.")
else:
    print("Doing some work.")

    pass # this may be different for different purposes.
    
    print("Doing some other work.")
```

where all print statements represent some tasks common across block repetitions.

There are quite a few blocks of code like this, and I'm trying to factor out the repetitions -- i.e., everything except the statements represented by `pass` in the above chunk.

In other words, I'm looking for something similar to a contextmanager that wraps around the `pass` statement, and is able to handles the if-else statement. Is there a good way to do this in Python?

Comment: Are you looking for contextlib.ExitStack, which lets you handle context managers dynamically?

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for. What is the repetitive part?

Comment: There's some good explanation about how to define your own context managers in Python [here](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function that takes a callback function for the part that's different.

```
def do_stuff(condition, callback):
    if condition:
        print("Doing some light work")
    else:
        print("Doing some work")
        callback()
        print("Doing some other work")
```

You could also rewrite this as a decorator that you use before the definitions of the callback functions.

Comment: You could add a `try:` `finally:` if they last step was important as implied by the context manager consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should look a little more broadly at your code and redesign it by applying the basic principles of [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming):

```
class BaseWorker:
    def do_work(self, condition):
        if condition:
            print("Doing some light work.")
        else:
            print("Doing some work.")
            self.specific_work()
            print("Doing some other work.")

    def specific_work(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class WorkerA(BaseWorker):
    def specific_work(self):
        """worker A processing"""
        ...


class WorkerB(BaseWorker):
    def specific_work(self):
        """worker B processing"""
        ...
```